# How to Requery a combobox of a subform inside a main form?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, combobox, subform

I'm a beginner in MS Access and this is my problem ;).

- *Home* is the name of the mainform
- *levisite* is the name of the subform
- *CasellaCombinata0* is the name of the combobox.

Here is the code  (VBA) associated to an event on a click on the combobox where I call the query named *LastVisit*:

```vb
Private Sub CasellaCombinata0_Click()
   Dim Variable1 As Date
   Variable1 = DLookup("reservationdate", "LastVisit")
   Me.DisSelected.Caption = "The last visit was: " & Variable1
End Sub
```

Here is the code (sql) of the query "LastVisit":

```sql
SELECT Max(reservation_date) AS reservationdate
FROM Appointment
WHERE (((Appointment.ID_SP) = TempVars!TempID) 
  And ((Appointment.ID_patient) = Forms![levisite].[CasellaCombinata0]));
```

I don't know if the last notation is correct: `Forms![levisite].[CasellaCombinata0]`. I get this error:

> Run-time error "2450" Application cannot find form '"levisite".

But when I run it directly to the subform it works and I don't know where is the problem. Thanks for the attention!

Comment: It should be: `Forms.Home.SubformControlName.Form.ComboBoxName`.

Comment: Thanks for answering me. SubformControlName in my case what it is? levisite?

Comment: It's the control name where your subform resides. Select it and go to properties > other to see its name.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I solved the problem because i was putting the name of the subform instead of the putting the subcontrolname that in my case was"SottomascheraSpostamento"

Comment: @KostasK., could write up an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is the following notation:

```
Forms.NavigationBar.Subcontrolname.Form.Comboxname
```

So in my case it was:

```
Forms.Home.SottomascheraSpostamento.Form.CasellaCombinata0
```

The subcontrol is not the name of the subform but it's where the subform resides.